# IllegalAccessException: Class BlockJUnit4ClassRunner can not access a member of class Abc with modifiers "private"

Tags: junit, parameterized, illegalaccessexception

Downloaded junit-4.12.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (both latest for the time being), but when I try to run my unit tests, I get this exception for private (or protected) fields with attribute [Parameter](http://junit.org/apidocs/index.html?org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html). When I change the fields to public, everything is fine.

Any comments?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that was my mistake, [Parameterized test documentation](http://junit.org/apidocs/index.html?org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) also defines those fields as public.